# Limit requests that users can send to 3 every 30 days. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, time, limit

I am learning to program and I am trying with Ruby on rails. I would like to restrict one functionality that allows users to send me introduction requests (3 introduction request per 30 days). I am not sure if I have to create a method first, for example:

```
def month
  where("created_at <?", Date.today - 30.days))
end
```

I don't know if that method is correct and if I can integrate it within this piece of code:

```
def create
  @introduction = CompanyIntroduction.create(intro_params)
  if current_user #Admin can edit the user name and email 
    @introduction.user = current_user
    @introduction.user_name = current_user.full_name
    @introduction.user_email = current_user.email
  end 
  if @introduction.save
    flash[:success] = "Thank you. Your request is being reviewed by TechIreland."
  else
    flash[:error] = @introduction.errors.full_messages
  end
  redirect_back(fallback_location: user_companies_path)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You have the time comparison backwards though, and the method (assuming it's on your model) should be a class method or a scope.

```
scope :in_the_last_month, -> { where('created_at > ?', Date.today - 30.days) }
# or more elegantly
scope :in_the_last_month, -> { where(created_at: 30.days.ago..) }
```

Then in the controller you can check how many requests were made recently.

```
if CompanyIntroduction.in_the_last_month.count >= 3
  # give some error
else
  # continue
end
```

This code is simple enough that you don't actually need to make it into a method, just the code in the controller is probably fine.

```
if CompanyIntroduction.where(created_at: 30.days.ago..).count >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I am trying with the if statement that you suggested, but I am wondering if there is any way to include a clause to only include requests from the current user.